# Cloudfront Function Headers not applied on all objects of S3 origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website on S3 which is served using Cloudfront. I have a Cloudfront Function associated to the distribution. My website's index page has all the response headers set but no headers are being set to the resources for that page that are on same bucket and served by same cloudfront distribution. What could be missing to set response headers to all resources?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.